Keep the longest record in a column for multiple entries
I am trying to filter in a query records that are returning multiple entries. I want to keep the longest records as it correlates to the furthest nested path. Example:
The simplified query:
SELECT DISTINCT itemID, itemPath from table_name

returns a data set similar to this:



ItemID
ItemPath




1
root/


1
root/subroot


1
root/subroot/sub-subroot


2
root/


2
root/subroot


2
root/subroot/sub-subroot


3
root/


3
root/subroot


4
root/


4
root/subroot


4
root/subroot/sub-subroot


4
root/subroot/sub-subroot/sub-sub-subroot


5
root/



I am wanting to return something like this:



ItemID
ItemPath




1
root/subroot/sub-subroot


2
root/subroot/sub-subroot


3
root/subroot


4
root/subroot/sub-subroot/sub-sub-subroot


5
root/



Where is keeps the longest record for each ItemID. I can't use MAX as it would only return the single longest record in the column and I don't want to set a character limit as the lengths are all variable.

What do you want returned when an item has 2 ItemPath values of equal length but different spelling?  I think you need to provide more realistic examples to ensure the solutions proposed meet your needs.

Hey @BartMcEndree the real world application is looking at device OU with multiple subnets. The OU will only have one final path as the devices are not in multiple OUs

Note that you can use MAX, you just have to combine it with GROUP BY as such:
SELECT itemID, max(itemPath) from table_name
GROUP BY itemID

By adding the GROUP BY you will aggregate only over the individual values of itemID, ensuring one record per id.

thanks, was stuck on the Distinct instead of looking at Group By.

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to identify the rows you want. Then, filtering is easy.
For example:
select itemid, itempath
from (
  select t.*, row_number()
              over (partition by itemid order by length(itempath) desc) as rn
  from table_name t
) x
where rn = 1

Result:
 itemid  itempath                                 
 ------- ---------------------------------------- 
 1       root/subroot/sub-subroot                 
 2       root/subroot/sub-subroot                 
 3       root/subroot                             
 4       root/subroot/sub-subroot/sub-sub-subroot 
 5       root/                                    

See running example at db<>fiddle.

You could try this:
SELECT ItemID, Max(ItemPath) as ItemPath FROM <your table> GROUP BY ItemID

where  is the name of your table.
It returns the following for me:
ItemID  ItemPath
1   root/subroot/sub-subroot
2   root/subroot/sub-subroot
3   root/subroot
4   root/subroot/sub-subroot/sub-sub-subroot
5   root/
